# Can i do the potentiation of a float negative number? - Haskell

Tags: haskell

im a student and im learning Haskell! The question is how can I do the potentiation of a float negative number?
For example, when i do this, i get an error

```
(-2)**2
Program error: argument out of range
```

Is there any solution to this issue?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: By ‘potentiation’, do you mean ‘exponentiation’?

Answer (score 3):

A negative number raised to an arbitrary real exponent is not, in general, a real number. One option is to use one of the power operations, `(^)` or `(^^)`, instead. `(^)` expects a non-negative integral power, while `(^^)` permits an arbitrary integral power but needs the result type to be in the `Fractional` class. Your other major option is to import `Data.Complex` and perform your `(**)` calculation using `Complex Double` instead of the default `Double`.

Answer (score 0):

The operator `**` is for powers with fractional exponents. Obviously, a power like `(-2) ** 0.5` makes no sense for real numbers.

You can use operator `^` for integral exponents: `(-2) ^ 2`.